# How do I modify the general icon on the top left corner of a pyqt window and the one in the task bar?

Tags: python, pyqt, icons

I'm seeking a way to modify the icon on the top left position of the window and also the icon in the task bar at the bottom of the screen

[image]
I would like use this one:

[image]

The answer of Netwave changed the icon of the window but not the one in the taskbar.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys 

class GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(os.path.join('icons','pulse.png'))))
        self.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = GUI(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it to the app:

```
app_icon = QIcon("path_to_file")
app.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
```

With your code would look like"

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app_icon = QIcon("path_to_file")
    app.setWindowIcon(app_icon)
    ex = GUI(app)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))
```

Comment: How simple It was. Do you know If I can modify the background color of the icon. I mean replaced the transparent part of the icon with a color?

Comment: yes, you can do that also by loading the image, modifiying it and the using that image for building the icon